# Issues in parsing json from asmx

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, asmx

I'm trying to parse json string which i receive from my asmx webservice through IIS. The string i'm receiving is as shown below:

```
"{\"Name\":\"Waqas Aslam\",\"Company\":\"ABC Systems AB\",\"Address\":\"myStreet 4\",\"Phone\":\"123456\",\"Country\":\"Sweden\"}"
```

The problem is that, i can successfully retrieve the response string, but i'm unable to parse it. Here's my code:

```
try{
        InputStream source = getJson(URL);
        String s = streamToString(source);

        Log.i(TAG, s);


        GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonb.create();

        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(s);
        Employee em = gson.fromJson(j.toString(), Employee.class);
        lblResult.setText(em.Company);          
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

here's method streamToString:

```
public static String streamToString(InputStream is) {
   //as per 64K size
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 65728);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       String line = null;
       try {
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line);
           }
       }
       catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
       finally {
           try { is.close(); }
           catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
       }

       return sb.toString();
   }
```

and here's class employee:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Employee {

            @SerializedName("Name")
            public String Name;

            @SerializedName("Company")
            public String Company;

            @SerializedName("Address")
            public String Address;

            @SerializedName("Phone")
            public String Phone;

            @SerializedName("Country")
            public String Country;
    }
```

Here's the exception i'm getting:

```
02-02 10:08:28.877: E/TestJSON(3223): org.json.JSONException: Value {"Name":"Waqas Aslam","Company":"ABC Systems AB","Address":"myStreet 4","Phone":"123456","Country":"Sweden"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

If i manually (by code) provide json string to the JSONObject, then it works fine, but not with the string i receive from server. Is there something i need to change at server side?
If you like, you may give a try to fetch json from my test server by using`HttpPost` from this URL `http://test1.phoniro.se/AndroidTestWebService/Service.asmx/TestJSON2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing, the JSON string you have there is invalid. **Remove** all the escape characters (i.e. `\"`) and try changing it to the following:

```
{
    "Name": "WaqasAslam",
    "Company": "ABCSystemsAB",
    "Address": "myStreet4",
    "Phone": "123456",
    "Country": "Sweden"
}
```

So to answer your question, modify your *server side* to produce valid JSON. My example above is perfectly valid JSON and you should not have any issues with Gson parsing it. [Here's](http://jsonlint.com/) a website you can use to validate your JSON output when you're unsure.

Comment: but the thing is, if i test that json string received from server in JQuery, it works fine.
Does JQuery omit/ignore escape characters itself?

Comment: @Waqas I can't say for sure if JQuery deals with the escape characters properly, but I can tell you that Gson doesn't.

Comment: hmmm, anyway thanks. Actually i already got it working few hours ago by modifying server side and your answer confirms that it was the problem with Json string i was receiving